# What's the probability that the distinct number appear in a size-k subset of n distinct number?

Tags: math, probability

What's the probability that the distinct number appear in a  size-k subset of n distinct numbers?

Let A be our target number, S be some the size-k subset of [1,2,3....n].
What's the probability that A is the one of k numbers in S? Many thanks.

PS: I can draw a condition tree diagram, and find the answer maybe the k/n.
But how can I think about it? Thanks again.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a question about mathematics rather than programming thus is better suited for the [Mathematics Stack Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/) site.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about probability and [math.se] instead of programming or software development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probability is indeed, as you mentioned,  `k/n`. Think about is this way: Let `x` be an element of `[1,2,...,n]`. There are `binom(n,k)` subsets of size `k` in total, and there are `binom(n-1,k-1)` subsets of size `k` that contain `x` (because `x` is chosen and we need to choose another `k-1` elements). Hence the probability of `x` to be contained in `S` is `binom(n-1,k-1)/binom(n,k)=k/n`.